# Dynamic photo gallery with jQuery

Tags: jquery, photo-gallery

I'd like to create a photo gallery with large (fit-to-window) photos, description overlays and dynamically extending (yet fixed number) thumbnail view. I have over 1000+ pics in a gallery and I'd like to load only the first 100 pics as thumbnails, and as the user scrolls the thumbnails, it would extend the list (appending to the end, removing from the head).

The best candidate for this is [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/). Do you know any similar site that does this, or is there any other tool you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [TN3 Gallery](http://www.tn3gallery.com/examples/tn3_eris_horizontal/) would do what you need. You can view thumbnails, it only preloads the next image in the sequence, so you don't tax the browser too much. The only thing I'm not sure of is whether it loads all the thumbnails at once... but it seems to do a good job of not taxing the browser in it's examples. It is nicely done - check it out.

If you're still looking for more samples..

Check out this list of great jQuery-based galleries that support large numbers of photos efficiently

[jQuery Image Galleries and Sliders](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-image-galleries-sliders-best-of/)